# How do I correctly instance a class to be referenced in other classes. Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static, instance

I'm currently working on a project where I have 2 separate "Managers". One was created successfully to instance itself on startup, and I can reference all of it's methods without a problem. I realized how useful this was so now I am trying to re-rig my other manager to follow the same instancing pattern, but whenever I call one of it's methods from a different class, I get "object reference not set to an instance of an object error at the reference line.

Here is the manager that works at its initialization:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using DG.Tweening;

// this class will take care of switching turns
public class TurnManager : MonoBehaviour {


// for Singleton Pattern
public static TurnManager Instance;

void Awake()
{
    Instance = this;
}
```

Here is a (successful) calling of a method inside the "TurnManager" from a different class:

```
TurnManager.Instance.StopTheTimer();
```

And here is a section of the other manager that does not successfully instance itself:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using DG.Tweening;

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public static DialogueManager Instance;

public delegate void VoidWithNoArguments();
public event VoidWithNoArguments DialogueEndEvent;


public AudioSource speechSounds;
public AudioClip speechSound;
public Image headshot;
public Text dialogueText;
public DeckSO deckForFight;

public Animator animator;

public bool dialogueActive;
private Queue<NPCAtributes> speakers;
private Queue<string> sentences;
private Queue<DialogueArray> lines;
private bool fightStart;
private PlayerController thePlayer;
private static bool UIExists;



// Use this for initialization
void awake()
{
Instance = this;

}

void Start()
{
    if (!UIExists) {
        DontDestroyOnLoad (transform.gameObject);
    UIExists = true;
    } else
        Destroy (gameObject);
    speakers = new Queue<NPCAtributes> ();
    sentences = new Queue<string>();
    lines = new Queue<DialogueArray> ();
    thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController> ();
}
```

A line where I will get an object reference error at run-time:

```
DialogueManager.Instance.DialogueEndEvent += SpawnDave;
```

Any Help would be Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Do you call DialogueManager.Instance on another scripts Awake method? From where do you call it?

Comment: In this line `DialogueManager.Instance.DialogueEndEvent += SpawnDave;` I am calling it in another script's start method, that only loads when I enter a different scene. Therefore the manager itself has been around for a good while before the instance line is called. The dialogue manager itself is preserved using the "don't destroy on load" line. I also know that this is just one of the lines that I have tried it on, and all have gotten the same object reference error.

Comment: You should put a null check on your assignment of your static singleton. If you create a second manager, you will reference the second manager instead of the first. Try something like `if(Instance == null) { Instance = this; }`

Comment: So, there is only one possiblity. Your DialogManager destroy itself on Start methods else situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot. This entire time, my "awake" method's "A" wasn't capitalized, and it ran it as a user defined method. I reverted all the changes to try to solve it back, and went back to the `instance=this` line. Thanks to everyone for the help, I never would've figured it out if you hadn't pointed out how awake wasn't being called.